# SQL join to find relavant codes and address

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Below table contain address information.

| Code | Code1 | Code2 | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DAN001 | DAN004 | DAN005 | ABC, Newyork. |
| DAN004 | DAN004 | DAN004 | Delhi, India |
| DAN005 | DAN005 | DAN005 | Ever, Belgium |

Please find table details below:

Each Code have associated code1 and code2 and address last column.
for example:

- DAN001 is associated with DAN004 and DAN005.
- Address for DAN001 is ABC, Newyork.
- Address for DAN004 is Delhi,India.
- Address for DAN005 is Ever, Belgium.

I am looking for the single SQL query, which will give me associated code1 and code2 and corresponding addresses for each codes in the single query for the given code.

I made below query but this is not working as excepted:

```
 select a.code, b.code1, b.address code1_address , c.code2, c.address code2_address
 from address a,address b, address c  where a.code='DAN001'
 and a.code1= b.code and a.code2=c.code;
```

I am using Oracle10g.

Excepted result:

DAN004, ABC Newyork, DAN005, EVER Belgium

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for `join`s?

```
select a.*, a1.address, a2.address
from address a left join
     address a1
     on a1.code = a.code1 left join
     address a2
     on a2.code = a.code2;
```

This uses `left join` in case any of the code columns are empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon for the feedback.